# Python datetime's isoformat() - shouldn't there be three options?

Tags: python, datetime

There are 3 ways to adhere to "iso8601" per wikipedia

[image: Wikipedia ISO 8601]

Is there a clean pythonic way to select which format to use?

`isoformat` only has *sep* and *timespec* arguments, neither of which achieve what I want. I currently just `string.replace()` a bunch and it's ugly

background: Python's .isoformat() outputs something like `2020-03-04T19:31:09.537073+00:00`, but our c++-based reciever is currently configured to accept `20200304T193109.537073Z`

Comment: `isoformat()` is just a convenience function. You can get any format you want with `strftime()`.

Comment: I guess I could also use datetime as a baseclass and create my own isoformat method

Comment: "currently configured": does that mean you can change it to be more standards-compliant?

Comment: `20200304T193109.537073Z` *is* iso8601 standards compliant. Both sides would require roughly the same amount of work to adopt to the other, just perusing my options here